# AWS Redshift query multiple schema's

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, database-schema, amazon-redshift, multiple-tables

Is it possible to query multiple schema's within my Redshift database and combine the results?

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, SUM(usage) AS totalUsage
FROM schemaOne.terms, schemaTwo.terms
```

will throw an error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: column reference "name" is ambiguous;

So, is this possible and would this be a good practice? I would like to create a schema for each client which will have it's own terms (tags) table and other tables.

**For example**

SchemaOne: terms

```
id,  name,  description,  usage
_______________________________
1    css    CSS is bla.   14
2    html   HTML rocks!   9
```

SchemaTwo: terms

```
id,  name,  description,  usage
_______________________________
1    css    CSS is cool.  8
2    other  x             4
```

Now I would like to combine the results, which could output something like:

```
name   totalUsage
_________________
css    22
html   9
other  4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First do `UNION ALL` in a derived table, then apply `GROUP BY`:

```
select name, sum(usage) as totalUsage
from
(
    select name, usage
    from SchemaOne.terms
    union all
    select name, usage
    from SchemaTwo.terms
) dt
group by name
```

Note that some products have `name` and `usage` as reserved words, so you may need to delimit them as `"name"` and/or `"usage"`.

Perhaps better performance version:

```
select name, sum(usage) as totalUsage
from
(
    select name, sum(usage) as usage
    from SchemaOne.terms
    group by name
    union all
    select name, sum(usage) as usage
    from SchemaTwo.terms
    group by name
) dt
group by name
```

**Original answer**:

If the same column name exists in more than one table, you have to qualify that column, i.e put the table name before the column name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT schemaOne.terms.name, SUM(usage) as totalUsage
FROM schemaOne.terms, schemaTwo.terms
```

Table aliases are convenient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1t.name, SUM(usage) as totalUsage
FROM schemaOne.terms s1t, schemaTwo.terms s2t
```

Comment: But what I'm looking for is to combine the results of both/multiple schema's

Comment: Combine how? Add some sample table data for your two tables, and the expected result.

Comment: I've added an example to my question.

Comment: Thanks, this works :) What does `dt` do and why are you grouping the results by the `name` column, wouldn't this be neglectable since you're only selecting the two columns?

Comment: `dt` is just a table alias for the derived table (with UNION ALL). Should be optional, but some dbms products require it.

Comment: The GROUP BY is required since you want name just as column, and also use the sum aggregate function. The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."